# Correct way to install Ioncube on EasyPHP Devserver v17?

Tags: zend-framework, easyphp, ioncube

What's the correct way to install Zend Optimiser and ionCube on EasyPHP Devserver v17 on my local Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Install with a zend_extension line for each. However check whether you have protected ionCube or Zend files. The Zend product has been dead for a few years so you may not need it, and you would only need the Loader for ionCube, at least locally, if you have encoded ionCube files. If you have a public Linux server the Loader can also provide malware protection and PHP error monitoring as part of the ionCube24 service, so there are other benefits to having it installed in that environment even if not using encoded files. If you want to improve performance, that will come from using PHP OP Cache.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Your info helped me sort the problem.